# Set axes limits in Matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, plot, real-time, axes, limits

I am trying to simulate a real time plot of an ECG signal using MATLAB GUI. For testing purposes I am trying to implement a sine wave that plots as if in real time. I am using a GUI with one button which starts plotting the sine wave, and a set of axes tagged as 'axes1'. The code below is extracted from the callback function for the start button:

```
%create a sine wave to plot
X=[0:0.1:25*pi];
X=transpose(X); 
Y=sin(X); 
[a,b] = size(X); 
hold on; 
%initialise axes limits
axis(handles.axes1,[0,a,-1,1]);
%plot sine wave 
for i = 1:a 
plot(handles.axes1,1:i,Y(1:i)); 
drawnow; 
pause(0.01); 
end
```

The result is a moving sine wave, but I am trying to define the axes limits beforehand so that they don't keep re-sizing as the wave is plotted. I have tried using the line

```
axis(handles.axes1,[0,1,-1,1])
```

To set the axes limits but it is not working as I would like it to and I'm not sure how to proceed from this point.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I have solved the problem by placing the line in question within the for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `...LimMode` [properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#XLimMode) to manual during the axes creation; that way they should not change when new data are plot. By default they are set at `auto`.

Eg:

```
set(handles.axes,'XLimMode','manual','YLimMode','manual');
```

Comment: Or use `xlim`, `ylim`, `axis`